# GDB: `continue` in hook-stop works every other time

Tags: gdb

I want to ignore breakpoint/watchpoint hits based on some condition. At first sight, using `continue` inside `hook-stop` seems to be the solution. It seems though, that GDB ignores/disables the hook after resuming execution, but then somehow reenables it, and then disables it again upon a hit, and so on.

Here's a minimal example with steps to reproduce.

The program we are going to debug ("1.c"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *f;
int foo()
{
  static int v = 0;
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", v);
  fflush(f);
  if (v++ == 42)
    return v;
  return foo();
}
int main()
{
  f = fopen("/tmp/log", "a");
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with e.g. `gcc -Og -g 1.c`.

Command file "cmd":

```
set $cont = 1

def hook-stop
    if ($cont == 1)
       python with open("/tmp/log", "a") as ofile: print("cont", file=ofile)
       continue
    end
end

b foo
r
```

Run: `rm /tmp/log; gdb -x cmd --args ./a.out`

gdb session:

```
Breakpoint 1, foo () at 1.c:4
(gdb) i b
breakpoint already hit 2 times
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Breakpoint 1, foo () at 1.c:4
(gdb) i b
breakpoint already hit 4 times
```

The resulting `/tmp/log`:

```
cont
0
1
cont
2
```

And if I keep hitting `c` it goes on like that: 2 3 cont 4 5 cont... i.e. the execution is resumed by the hook, but only every other time.

**Is this a GDB bug?**

*How do I go about automatically resuming execution based on some complex condition (in my original problem I have a watchpoint, but I want to ignore the hits in functions I am not interested in)?* — Edit: This part is answered already, thanks to Employed Russian for setting me on the right path. As another person happened to wonder about the same thing almost on the same day, I posted my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56774099/2104472), the only remaining magic wold be the filter itself: `return gdb.selected_frame().name() in ["foo", "bar"]`.

My GDB version is 8.3.

---

Prior to posting this, I stared at the implementation for a while — but haven't actually tried debugging it yet. This code in `infrun.c` looks suspicious:

```
normal_stop (void):
  ...

  TRY
    {
      execute_cmd_pre_hook (stop_command);
    }
  CATCH (ex, RETURN_MASK_ALL)
    {
      exception_fprintf (gdb_stderr, ex,
                 "Error while running hook_stop:\n");
    }
  END_CATCH

      /* If the stop hook resumes the target, then there's no point in
     trying to notify about the previous stop; its context is
     gone.  Likewise if the command switches thread or inferior --
     the observers would print a stop for the wrong
     thread/inferior.  */
  if (stop_context_changed (saved_context))
    {
      do_cleanups (old_chain);
      return 1;
    }
```

Comment: "I want to ignore breakpoint/watchpoint hits based on some condition." -- you realize that GDB supports conditional breakpoints directly, right? https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html

Comment: Hm, actually, I did not realize _watchpoints_ could be made conditional as well. I will try that. I've also learned about "Breakpoint Command Lists": `commands` could be used instead of `hook-stop` to specify series of commands to execute for individual watchpoints.