# How to continue the exection after hitting breakpoints in gdb?

Tags: gdb

When debuging a simple program in gdb, I want to continue the execution automatically after hitting breakpoints. As far as I know, there are two methods to accomplish it:

1) use `hook-stop`.

```
define hook-stop
continue
end
```

But it seems the `hook-stop` is trigged only once. When another breakpoint is hit next time, the execution still stops.

2) use `gdb.events.stop.connect()`.

```
def handle_stop_event(event):
    if isinstance(event, gdb.BreakpointEvent):
        gdb.execute('continue')

gdb.events.stop.connect(handle_stop_event)
```

This method works well. But if there are too many breakpoints been hit, an error `"Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow."` occurs.
It seems because of recursive call. I'm wondering why the `gdb.execute('continue')` would cause this issue.

I searched online and still didn't find a solution.

PS: gdb version 7.11.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Any advice would be appreciate! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, `continue` inside `hook-stop` doesn't work properly. Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56762809/2104472) I posted yesterday?

I think, the best approach here is writing a convenience function in python and setting a conditional breakpoint. Or using `commands` — see the "Breakpoint Command Lists" section of the GDB user manual.

Here's how do to it (also described in the manual).

The python module:

```
import gdb

class should_skip_f(gdb.Function):
    def __init__ (self):
        super (should_skip_f, self).__init__("should_skip")

    def invoke(self):
        return True  # Your condition here

should_skip_f()
```

```
(gdb) b <your target> if !$should_skip()
```

Or add the condition to existing breakpoints with

```
(gdb) condition <BNUM> !$should_skip()
```

The only downside is that you have to set the condition for each breakpoint individually, but that's scriptable.  Also, I think, the `commands` syntax allows you to add commands to a list of breakpoints at once.

```
'commands [LIST...]'
'... COMMAND-LIST ...'
'end'
     Specify a list of commands for the given breakpoints.  The commands
     themselves appear on the following lines.  Type a line containing
     just 'end' to terminate the commands.
```

---

As for the recursion — yeah, that's a bad "design" of a debugger script (if one should talk about design of one-off throwaway things). You can examine what happens there if you extend your python script like so

```
import inspect
...
  def handle_stop_event(event):
    ...
    print(len(inspect.stack())) # Or you can print the frames themselves...
```

The Python interpreter doesn't know that execution does not return from `gdb.execute("continue")`, so the Python stack frames for invocations of this function are never destroyed.

You can increase max stack size for the interpreter, but like I said, this script does not seem like the best solution to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding condition to breakpoints is not what I want. As you mentioned, I tried to increase max stack size previously, which was not a better solution for me too. But using `commands` works well in my case.  It seemed I misuse the `commands` before.  Although, I didn't figure out how to use `commands` in a single `gdb.execute()` call.